How can I identify VDP on VOR 1 runway 36 at KOCF
at Ocala international airport (KOCF), they have VOR runway 36 approach. The VDP is 2.7 NM away from the OCF vortac. But my aircraft is not equipped with DME. How can I identify the VDP without using DME?
(My aircraft is equipped with GPS and Dual VOR)
At first I thought I can use GPS to see the distance but GPS substitute is not allowed on final approach segment…


It does seem strange to have it be a "VOR approach" with "DME required" rather than just calling it a "VOR/DME approach."

“VOR/DME” is no longer the current standard naming convention. If DME is required in the procedure (which it is, for the missed approach), then it should have the note in the pilot briefing bar. This also applies to an ILS or LOC procedure.

A VOR/DME approach indicates that DME is required for the final approach segment (FAS).  If DME is required outside of the FAS (FAF to MAP), a note is applied.

If an approach is VOR/DME approach, can you use GPS to identify waypoint on a final approach segment?

Yes. You cannot use GPS as the only means of lateral navigation on the final approach segment. I recommend you read AC 90-108 or the draft AC 90-119, section 11.4.6.

@wbeard52, that naming convention is outdated. The current naming convention is to simply call it VOR. The equipment requirement box is for any equipment required between the IAF through the missed approach.

@Timbo. Do you have a reference for your statement?  My understanding is the equipment required from the FAF to MAP is listed in the approach title.  i.e VOR/DME.  If there is equipment needed from the IAF through the MAP but not on the final approach segment (FAS), it will be listed with a note on the chart somewhere.

@wbeard52 With the missed approach point being the OCF VOR, you don't seem to need DME until you get to the holding fix.

@RalphJ  I agree with you.  That is why there is a note that DME is required but because DME is not required for the FAS, it is not in the approach title.  A cursory look of the newest terminal procedures (2413) shows two changed procedures with DME still in the title.  Both require DME for the fAS.  https://aeronav.faa.gov/d-tpp/2412/compare_pdf/06239nda_cmp.pdf  https://aeronav.faa.gov/d-tpp/2413/compare_pdf/00367vyty3_cmp.pdf

@RalphJ how do you get to the MAP without using DME? from my understanding I guess you need to measure distance (16NM) on the R355 on OCF VOR by using DME unless you use the suitable rnav (GPS)

@ShinO The MAP, the point at which you must go missed, is the VOR. You need DME or GPS to identify the missed approach holding fix, which is the 16 mile point.

@wbeard52 it was a change to the 8260.19 that happened years ago. https://cfiruss.blogspot.com/2018/05/goodbye-dme-hello-equipment.html?m=1
In the current 8260.19, it is covered in section 8-6-9.

DME is required, and there’s no way to identify VDP without DME.
↑
this is my first thought but actually you can use GPS to execute the missed approach

DME is required for the missed approach. That said, you can still use GPS to identify the VDP. You just can’t use it for final approach lateral guidance.

can you still use GPS to identify missed approach holding point?

yes, absolutely.
